# Using Object.defineProperty for keys of child object?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I'm trying to update an object inside an object. But instead it is creating a concatenated key.

```
Object.defineProperty(ParentX.prototype, 'ChildX.active', { value: true } );
```

This is overwriting the ChildX object and making a key "ParentX.ChildX.active".

Comment: this is overwriting nothing unless a property called "Childx.active" was defined previously. If active is a property of ChildX then what you just did will have no effect on it whatsoever.

Comment: @mpm maybe I'm not reading the console output properly, either way I need to update the ChildX object and this isn't working

Comment: Given an existing property `ParentX.prototype.Childx` : `Object.defineProperty(ParentX.prototype.Childx,'active',{value:true})` . I'm not sure what you mean by "update" at first place.

Comment: @mpm I just mean set

Comment: @mpm getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" with that code

Comment: "Given an existing property". I said. If ChildX doesn't exist before invoking that function it's not going to work.